# gcc inline asm / constraints / "r" relates to "l" like "g" to ...?

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, inline-assembly, thumb

I'm trying to compile this for an ARM Cortex-M0+ (STM32G030) with *arm-none-eabi-gcc*:

```
asm("ldrb %0, [%1, %2]\n" : "=l" (v) : "l" (R.a+(o&~31)) , "g" (o&31));
```

where the variable o might be known already at compile time or later at run time (then i would use the constraint "l", because it has to be a lo register (r0-r7)... i use those 16bit thumb instructions).

Is there a constraint, that forces gcc to use a lo register, if a value is unknown at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

seems like, i can just give multiple constraints and gcc chooses the best one:

```
asm("ldrb %0, [%1, %2]\n" : "=l" (v) : "l" (R.a+(o&~31)) , "li" (o&31));
```

*yay*

Comment: That works, though also check with clang.  E.g. clang really loves to use memory operands for `"rm"` constraints even where it makes no sense at all.

Comment: You might also consider using `if (__builtin_constant_p(o))`.  The [builtin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) is resolved at compile time, which means that only one branch ends up in the compiled code.  NB: Non-optimized builds can be *very* conservative about their predictions here.  The benefits come during optimized builds.